# How to Convert Double to Hexadecimal using javascript with 0x

Tags: javascript, hex

I have a variable like this:

```
var currency = "4,990.17"
currency.replace(/[$,]+/g,"");
var currency2 = parseDouble(currency)-0.1;
```

How can I set `currency2` to be hexadecimal with 0x in front of it?

I would like my string hexadecimal value of 4999.17 to become:

> 0x137E.2B851EB851EB851EB852

Comment: Why are you subtracting `0.1`?  Where did `4999.17` come from - did you mean `4990.17`?

Answer (score 1):

Once converted to a number you can call .toString([radix]) ( [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) ) with an optional *radix* which is in the range 2 through 36 specifying the base to use for representing numeric values.

```
var currency = 4990.17; 
hexCurrency = currency.toString(16);
console.log(hexCurrency);
```

This returns `137E.2B851EB851EB851EB852` or you can add 0x by doing
`hexCurrency = "0x" + currency.toString(16);`

Comment: Shouldn't the radix, in this case, be 16?

Comment: Yes it should be sorry, updated the answer now. Not sure how that slipped